# aws-cdk construct - Certification Manager

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-certificate-manager, aws-cdk, troposphere

Below is my understanding on talking to AWS API(REST) using [SDK approach](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/tree/master/service) or CF template generation tools(like [AWS_CDK](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk) or Troposphere)

[image]

---

Working with AWS certification manager, we would like to create private root CA using aws-cdk constructs.

But the [cdk-documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-certificatemanager.html) does not support any construct to create root CA

---

On troposphere side, it is the same [story](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/troposphere/certificatemanager.py), no support for creating root CA

---

[aws_sdk](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/acmpca) **has support** for creating root CA, but state maintenance is the issue.

---

My preference is to pick aws_cdk, but,

What is the current status on this api level support to create private root CA, using aws-cdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudformation does not support private Root CA Resources (view [the supported resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_CertificateManager.html)). Therefore cdk and troposphere can not provide support for it.

You can create a Lambda backed Custom Resource that adds support for the acm pca stuff (take a look at the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html)). You could use `cdk` to create the CustomResource and a python lambda that wraps the `acm pca` API calls.

Comment: I created a custom resource for a iam SamlProvider (which is not supported by Cloudformation as well). You can take a look here https://github.com/ventx/aws-cdk-library/blob/master/lib/constructs/SamlProviderConstruct.ts